# Unable to reference Google Play Services in Android Studio (gradle)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am following Google's [getting started guide for Play gaming services on Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart). I have downloaded the [basic samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) and imported them into Android Studio. Now I have a problem; it appears that "android.support.v4.*" and "com.google.android.*" are not a referenced library. I double checked the build.gradle's and synced the gradle files once more. Nothing changed, the two packages do not exist. According to the tutorial it should have worked fine. Sometimes I get a notice saying that I need to install the Google Repository from the Android SDK Manager, but when I go into the Android SDK Manager the Google Repository is already downloaded. Am I missing something?

Here are the build.gradle's so nobody has to go digging:

Top-level:

```
// this is the parent build configuration for all the sample projects.
// for more information on gradle build files when used in a multi-project build, see
// http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

// allprojects apply to every project
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    ext {
        android_compile_version = 23
        android_version = '23.0.1'
        android_min_sdk_version = 9

        appcompat_library_version = '23.0.1'
        support_library_version = '23.0.1'
        gms_library_version = '8.1.0'
    }
}
```

Module-specific (libraries/BaseGameUtils)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('appcompat_library_version')) {
        ext.appcompat_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('support_library_version')) {
        ext.support_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('gms_library_version')) {
        ext.gms_library_version = '8.1.0'
    }

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:${gms_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${gms_library_version}"
}

android {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_compile_version')) {
        ext.android_compile_version = 23
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_version')) {
        ext.android_version = '23'
    }

    compileSdkVersion android_compile_version
    buildToolsVersion android_version
}
```

Comment: Latest Play Service library version is `8.4.0` and support library version is `23.1.1` - you could try that after updating SDK tools in Android Studio. You need to have downloaded latest libraries before you can reference to them.

Comment: @Sharj I made sure my SDK tools were up to date and that the Google Repository and Android supports were up to date, as well as changing my gradle build files to the versions you gave. There was no change, neither package can be found.

Comment: Check the full message error if the dependency is correct.

Comment: @pjrader1, are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @d.datul1990 Yes. It seems that nothing I can do loads the Google Play Services into my project.

Comment: @pjrader1, can you post the message that you received?

Answer (score 0):

Addition information based on @Sharj's solution.

First of all you have to launch the SDK manager. Download and install the following files located under "*extras*": Google repository.

Restart android studio and open the build gradle file. You must modify your build.gradle file to look like this under dependencies and synchronise your project. Use the latest play services library version. If its an old version, android studio will highlight it. After that clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I have made sure I have the most recent version of Google Repository in the SDK manager. I restarted Android Studio, made absolutely sure the version of the Play services was up to date, but still no luck.